# Issue with Action support inside a selectlist

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I am working creating a vf page, that has a selectlist showing list of Sobjects. Once anyone sobject is selected it has to display the fields in another selectlist. 
I tried but I am unable to get the expected output. Dont know how to fix it. Kindly help.

**Controller:**

```
public class Workbenchlike {
public string selectedobj {get; set;}
public map<string, schema.sobjectType> selectobjs {get; set;}
public map<string, schema.sobjectField> fieldnam {get; set;}

 public workbenchlike(){
    selectobjs = schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    system.debug('selectedobject' +selectedobj);
 }

public pagereference getfieldnames(){
  schema.sobjecttype obj = schema.getglobaldescribe().get(selectedobj); 
  fieldnam = obj.getDescribe().fields.getMap(); 
  return null;
 }
}
```

**Vf page:**

```
<apex:page controller="Workbenchlike" >
<style>
 td{
     text-align:center;
 }
</style>
<apex:form >

<div style="text-align:center;font-size:20px">

    Select from the list  :-
<apex:outputPanel >
  <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedobj}" >
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!selectobjs}"/>
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getfieldnames}" reRender="table"/>

   </apex:selectList>
</apex:outputPanel>

</div>
   <div style="text-align:center; font-size:15px">
    <table id="table" >
    <tr> 
       <td>
           FieldNames:<br/>
         <apex:selectList size="4" value="{!fieldnam}" ></apex:selectList>
        </td>
           <td>
              Selected Values:<br/>
             <apex:selectList ></apex:selectList>
           </td>
       </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
  </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally did it! thought of sharing this so that it would be helpful for someone!

VF page:

````
    <style>
        td{
        text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form >
<apex:outputPanel id="error">
        <apex:messages />
</apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:pageBlock >

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" collapsible="false">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                     <apex:outputLabel value="Select from the list  :-" />
                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!strObjectName}" multiselect="false" >
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!lstObjNames}"/>
                        <apex:actionSupport action="{!retriveFieldNames}" event="onchange" reRender="filedname,error"/>  
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:outputPanel id="filedname">
            <div style="text-align:center; font-size:15px"  >
                <table>
                    <tr> 
                        <td>
                           <b>FieldNames:</b><br/>
                            <apex:selectList size="6" value="{!getfields}" multiselect="true" id="getfie" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!lstfieldNms}" />
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getquery}" reRender="values,button"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <b>Selected Values:</b><br/>
                            <apex:selectList size="6" value="{!selval}" id="values"  >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!selvalues}"></apex:selectOptions>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <apex:outputPanel id="button">
                        <apex:commandButton value="clear selected" action="{!clearsel}"  reRender="values,button" rendered="{!test}"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Query" action="{!query}" rendered="{!test}" reRender="input" />
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <apex:outputPanel id="input">

                <apex:inputTextarea value="{!inputrec}" style="font-size:20px; height:100px; width:500px" />

                </apex:outputPanel>

            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
[![The output would look like this][1]][1]
**And the Controller**

public class Workbenchlikes {
    public string strObjectName {get;set;}
    public list<SelectOption> lstObjNames {get; set;}
    public list<selectOption> lstfieldNms {get; set;}
    public list<string> getfields {get; set;} 
    public string selval {get; set;}
    public list<selectOption> selvalues {get; set;}
    public boolean test {get; set;}
    public string inputrec {get; set;}
    public workbenchlikes(){
        retriveObjectNames();
    }

    public void retriveObjectNames() {
        lstObjNames = new list<SelectOption>();
        lstObjNames.add(new selectOption('==Select One==', '==Select One==', false));
        map<string, schema.sobjectType> selectobjs = schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        for ( schema.sobjecttype objIterator : selectobjs.values()) {
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = objIterator.getDescribe();
            lstObjNames.add(new SelectOption(objResult.getname(), objResult.getlabel()));
        }
               system.debug('lstObjNames ===>  '+lstObjNames);
    }

    public void retriveFieldNames(){
    lstfieldNms = new list<selectOption>();

        system.debug('strObjectName ======>  ' +strObjectName);


        schema.sobjecttype obj = schema.getglobaldescribe().get(strObjectName);
        if(obj !=null){
        Map<string, schema.sobjectField> objfield = obj.getdescribe().fields.getMap();
        for(schema.sobjectfield fiIterator : objfield.values()){
        schema.describefieldresult fieldres =fiIterator.getDescribe();
        lstfieldNms.add(new selectoption(fieldres.getname(), fieldres.getname()));
        }    
        }else{
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please select An Object'));
        }

    }
    public void clearsel(){
    if(selvalues != null){

     selvalues.clear();
     test = false;
     }
    }
    public void getquery(){
    selvalues = new list<selectOption>();
    if(getfields.size() == 0){
    selvalues.clear();
    }else{
    test = true;
    system.debug('test'+test);
    for(integer i=0; i< getfields.size(); i++){
selvalues .add(new selectOption(getfields[i], getfields[i]));
    }
    }
    }
    public void query(){
    map<integer,string> strl = new map<integer,string>();
    for(integer i=0 ; i<getfields.size(); i++){
    strl.put(i,getfields[i]);
    }
    system.debug('strl===>' +strl);
    inputrec = 'select '+string.join(strl.values(),',')+' from ' +strObjectName;
    }
    }```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OquiZ.png
````

Answer (score 0):

give an Id to you another selectlist (fieldnam) and reRender that onchange of your first selectList.

To Add .. Look at the following code ..

`<apex:page controller="YourCustomCntrller">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Object Names"/>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>

                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedobj}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!selectobjs}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="shippingOption"/>
                </apex:selectList>

            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Field Names"/>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!fieldname}" id="shippingOption">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!fieldnames}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>`

Now form Your code....

Call your apex method on render of SelectList not from actionSupport, if you have written a getter method, be careful not use **get** with your method name in VF page...

As your apex menthod name is **getfieldnames**, you have to call **fieldnames** in your VF page.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hi Avinash, It didn't work. The method itself is not called from action support. I put system.debug inside the getfieldnames() method and found that the method itself not called for onchange event.

Comment: Please check the edits, hope that will help @S.Sujendran